# AWK insert line after first match and insert blank line if next line is not pattern

Tags: awk

I have following changelog like file

```
#1.2.3

#InsertPart

#1.2.2
```

or

```
#1.2.3

#InsertPart

- something

#1.2.2
```

And desired output is

```
#1.2.3

#InsertPart

- new inserted line

#1.2.2
```

or

```
#1.2.3

#InsertPart

- new inserted line
- something

#1.2.2
```

I was able to insert a line after #InsertPart with following script

```bsh
awk '1;!inserted && /# InsertPart/{c=2}c && !--c{print "- new inserted line"; inserted=1}'
```

But I'm stuck with inserting a blank line only if pattern `#x.x.x` is on next line. So Ive ended with following output

```
#1.2.3

#InsertPart

- new inserted line
#1.2.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are printing the line first and then deciding to do other processing, rather than doing the insertion stuff first and then printing the line.

You want to insert the new stuff 2 lines after the magic marker, and you want to add a blank line there as well if the line starts with `#`.

```
awk '/#InsertPart/ { c = 3 }
     --c == 0 { print "- new inserted line" }
     c == 0 && /^#/ { print "" }
     {print $0}'
```

I have written the code out in the straight forward way, rather than the shortest (e.g. "{print $0}" rather than "1") to make it clearer. The `--c == 0` decrements c and compares the new value of c to 0.

Comment: I 've been pwned!

Comment: That's it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

give this a try

```
awk -v line='- new inserted line' '/#InsertPart/ {printf "%s\n\n%s\n", $0, line; next}; 1' yourfilename
```

Comment: This unconditionally adds a blank line after the `- new inserted line`, whilst the OP seems to want to only add a blank line if the line after the inserted text starts with `#` (or maybe not add a blank line if the line starts with a `-`).